# Basic Operational Concepts Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, fasm

I learned some x86 Assembly in fasm a while back. I am aware of the instruction named ADD. e.g.:

```
ADD eax,edx ; Precisely ADD destination,source .
The output gets stored in eax.
```

But today I read a book on Computer Organization by Carl Hamacher and it says:

```
Add LOCA,R0
"This instruction adds the operand at memory location LOCA to the operand in a register in the processor, R0, and places the sum into register R0."

ADD R1,R0
This instruction adds the contents of register R1 and R0 and places the sum in R0.
```

What is the meaning of this? It defies to whatever I studied before. The results get stored in the left placement. Is this book even correct, or am I mistaken? (Page 1.3).

Comment: Not all assembly language is the same. In some the source is on left and destination is on right. Intel syntax happens to be destination followed by source. Whatever you are reading is for something other than Intel (intel x86 doesn't have r0 and r1 for example)

Comment: So, are you suggesting that there are platforms where **ADD source,destination** can be a thing? Thanks btw.

Comment: ADD source, destination and ADD destination, source are the same thing. It is up to the assembler to create the underlying machine code associated with instruction. There are a number of assemblers for x86 architecture. Most use an Intel style where destination followed by source (like NASM, MASM) but GNU assembler uses (by default) AT&T syntax where source is first, destination second. It is up to the assembler to convert its syntax to machine code. It is up to the developer of an assembler to specify the syntax.

Comment: Thanks mate, I am 19 and very passionate about kernels and low level stuff. Your help made my day better. +999k respekt

Comment: Each CPU has it's own instruction set, so the `add` at Intel and `add` at ARM are most likely somewhat different (and I'm ignoring the obvious difference like different names of general purpose registers and different binary encoding), like they may set different/-ly flags (or there are also CPUs which don't use flags at all), etc. But even on the same platform, like x86, there are assemblers with different syntax, which will produce the exactly same machine instruction, like `add eax,edx` in MASM/NASM/FASM/.. vs `addl %edx,%eax` in GAS, but their syntax differ even in the argument order...

Comment: The CPU does execute only the final binary machine code, so the assembler creator can basically modify anything about instruction name/syntax/special characters as they wish, because that textual source code is assembled by assembler into object file or binary file - where the real instruction op-codes are stored. At that binary level the assembler creator must conform to the CPU design, and produce the correct opcode (like `0x01 0xD0` for `add eax,edx` on x86 in 32b mode), but on the source level they can even rename `add` to "addition", if they wish, that's up to them.

Comment: it gets worse when you read third party books as they are often written using a tool and language, sometimes that tool is no longer available or has changed it syntax such that you cant use the books examples, etc.  in addition to the destination first/last thing.  x86 in particular is well known for the destination first/last thing, others (Im sure there are exceptions) tend to be one way or the other and stay that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off there are many different instruction sets, x86 is only one and it has evolved over decades with instructions being added and the defintion of how older instructions worked being changed or re-interpreted.

Second, assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program that reads the assembly language.  Unlike C or Python or JAVA or other where there is a clear definition that in particular everyone conforms to.  Assembly language is and can be defined however the author of the assembler wants.  No rules on the language, the only rules if any are governed by the hardware, for the tool to be useful you need to generate executable machine code.

Historically the chip vendor or in the case of IP cores, the core vendor provides their own documentation with the machine code defined and an assembly language there as well, someone somewhere be it that vendor or someone on their behalf has created an assembler that conforms to that language, and in the case of x86

```
add ah,bl
```

means ah = ah + bl

Someone else came along later (and this tool has a habit of doing this changing the assembly language to be incompatible with the chip/core vendors tools) and created/ported an assembler where

```
add ah,bl
```

means bl = bl + ah

The language differences are not just limited to destination first or last, the whole language including directives are part of the language, and even if you have AT&T syntax (destination last vs intel syntax remember intel created and makes these processors has destination first) on two or more different assemblers the rest of the syntax can be incompatible, as you should know from fasm.

Intel with its original definition made this more complicated by overloading the mov mnemonic rather than isolating register to register, memory to register, etc.  Other instruction sets do things like

```
ldrb r0,[r1]
ldr r0,[r1]
```

to show this is an 8 or 32 bit read (load) from memory at some address.  No other syntax is required, but for the x86, historically things like

```
mov [bx], 5
```

which instruction is that there is more than one

```
mov word ptr [bx], 5
```

okay that helps but some assemblers you had to use capital letters not lower case, etc.

So just like programming Python vs JAVA you need to know the syntax of the language you are programming.  with x86 you can try things like

```
mov bx,5
mov 5,bx
```

and see which one if any it complains about or maybe it requires

```
mov %bx,5
mov 5,%bx
```

to get one of the errors to go away, another assembler another assembly language.

then you get into other targets like arm, mips, etc. and their syntax and/or instructions will be different from x86 in some way.  then among the various assemblers for that target there can and will be language differences.   For some reason the folks that port gnu assembler tend to create languages that are not compatible with the language defined by the chip/IP vendor.  Its not one person doing it just a somewhat consistent theme.

Short answer, not broken, somewhat expected.  Syntax is tied to the tool not the target.

Comment: I don't have any words to thank you for such an informative answer. Being a CSE 2yr student, information like this helps me build strong basics and stay ahead of my class and teachers. +infinite respekt for u mate

Comment: another thing is number syntax, before C really became widespread (many many years after it was invented) wouldnt be uncommon to describe hex numbers as $7A  or early intel syntax 7Ah  or if it is a bigger number 0C3h since C3h is a label/string instead of a number.   Once the C syntax really penetrated and we got used to typing 0x7A or 0xC3 the assemblers started to support that syntax.  And then some eventually dropped the trailing h notation.

Comment: some companies back in the day were octal based, down to the instructions being broken into 3 bit fields, some went so far as to have a 9 bit byte and 36 bit word.  the pdp-11 being one that despite what you think is still around.  and there is a gcc backend and binutils port being maintained.  that assembly language is quite modified from the original and documented....

Comment: `mov %bx,5` in AT&T syntax is `mov [5],bx` ... so it will gladly compile (I think, didn't verify)... one safe bet is to simply know what you are using, other is to check listing file/binary disassembly....

Comment: was going for a constant not an address hoping that the constant would fail since it is not an address.  but I guess that depends on the assembler...

Comment: @old_timer the constant in AT&T is `mov %bx,$5` (this one should fail) ... you can't win over AT&T, it's far too inferior (my personal taste, if somebody finds it better than Intel, feel free to live like that, but don't ask me to check your source code... :D )